# Running multiple find and sed in a bash file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, find

I have the code below

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i  's#<![endif]>##g' {} +
find . -type f -exec sed -i  's#<script src="/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js?v=201425100529"></script>##g' {} +   
find . -type f -exec sed -i  's# <!--[if lt IE 9]>##g' {} +
```

in a bash file.

If I run the lines directly in terminal it works, but If I run them together in a sh file I have an error:

> find: missing argument to '-exec'

Comment: also, i'm not sure that search pattern like `[endif]` or `[if lt IE 9]` is correct (you certainly want `\[endif\]`)  and need to escape some special character like `[`for class definition in this case

Answer (score 2):

The reason the `command` execution succeeds but the `script` failed is,

when the script gets executed the `find` command searches for all files and directories in the current execution path ( as `.` is used in `find`). Again this also includes the `script` itself. This creates the script to be overwritten/modified by the `sed`.

And so instead of keeping the script in the same directory when the file edits needs to be done, the script can be kept in some other directory and an `absolute path` can be give to the `find` command.

And it is also recommended to terminate commands with `\;` to indicate the end of arguments.

Always use `bash` to execute scripts instead of `sh` which means `bourne shell` . Generally `bash` will be a symlink for `sh` but it will run in a compatibility mode which causes `bash` to loose modern functions.

```
#!/bin/bash

find /Absolute/path -type f -exec sed -i  's#<!\[endif\]>##g' '{}' \;
find /Absolute/path -type f -exec sed -i  's#<script src="/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js?v=201425100529"></script>##g' '{}' \;
find /Absolute/path -type f -exec sed -i  's# <!--\[if lt IE 9\]>##g' '{}' \;
```

Comment: Even if this modifies itself that wouldn't affect the current execution of the script (only the next running of the script). `+` is a valid argument to `-exec` and is preferable in cases where multiple files may be found and can be processed at once; it cuts down on the number of executions necessary to process all the files. Using `bash` is only a good idea when one needs to use `bash` features in other cases it is a poor idea since it makes it harder to know when you've strayed out of the realm of sh-compatibility and into bash-specific behaviour (and being sh-compatible is a good thing).

Comment: @EtanReisner yes `+` can be used but the way `-exec cmd \;` and `-exec  cmd +` are different. I wanted to see if that makes any difference. And regarding the `bash` there is no point in executing scripts with `sh` when the user is using `bash` as his default shell.

Comment: @KingsleySchmid can you please try adding single quotes `'{}'` around the braces. And also please not that you may need to add `\` to the character classes within the `sed`. I have update these changes in the answer.

Comment: What the user's default shell is doesn't matter. What matters is whether the script will ever need to be run on any other system at any point and whether the person writing the script wants to understand when they are using bash specifics versus compatible sh functions. The only difference I'm aware of between `\;` and `+` is how many files are given to the command at once.

Comment: Hi all I found that adding '{}' quote around the braces makes a difference. See link : http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm and without the + sign the query takes longer than necessary to run.

Comment: Good the issue has been found, the difference between `+` and the other is that with `+` all files are given as a single argument to the `sed` command, but with the other method each file will be a separate argument and thus runs as a separate process for each file.